# What is the alternative for ArWorldMap(iOs) in Android ArCore

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, arkit, arcore

I found this **[ArWorldMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap)** in iOs, which stores anchors locally and reuse whenever we want.

What is the Alternative for Android ArCore. I need to achieve similar functionality locally, what could be the possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for ARCore Cloud Anchors.

More on that here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/cloud-anchors

Same deal as ARWorldMap in iOS.

Comment: it is cloud based one right. is it possible to achieve locally like ArWorldMap ?

Comment: So afaik, the map file is still available locally (just like ARWorldMap), if you disconnect from the internet. But yes, at some point at initialization you'll have to connect to the internet.

Comment: Hi can you tell me how to get the map files locally.?